# lightning:input accepting xml document in spite of not included in "accept" attribute .(Microsoft Edge specific issue)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightninginput

I have following lightning:input of type file:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="fileInputId"
                 type="file"
                 label=" "
                 multiple="false"
                 name="fileupload"
                 accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp, image/gif, .zip, .doc, .docx, .rtf, .ppt, .pptx, .xls, .xlsx, .pdf, .txt"
                 onchange="{!c.showSelectedFile}"
                 class="slds-file-selector__dropzone slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__text slds-form-element__label"/>
```

When I browse files, it shows me files of type .xml and I am able to select it. I know this can be avoided by client side logic, but is there any standard way/known issue for this?

This behaviour is observed only in Microsoft Edge and not in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: The root source of the problem may be that docx, pptx and xlsx are all forms of xml files.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce  it. With this code xml file isn't visible for me from system explorer...

Comment: The "accept" parameter is only a *hint*. The browser is free to ignore/modify the list, and all browsers currently allow users to choose All Files as an alternative option.

Comment: @sfdcfox: If I remove .pdf from my accept list, it does not show me PDF files for selection. So I guess the "accept" parameter is working for other cases than XML

Comment: @crmprogdev: It is also allowing me to add any files like .exe or .mp4 that are outside of "accept"